# Own version of strncpy shouldn't work, but it does

Tags: c, arrays, character

so here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXOUTPUT 10

void copy_n(char des[], char src[], int n);

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  char output[MAXOUTPUT];
  copy_n(output, "SomeTestInputHere", 26);

  printf("%s\n", output);
  for(i=0;output[i]!='\0';i++)
    printf("%c\n", output[i]);

  return 0;
}

void copy_n(char des[], char src[], int n)
{
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<MAXOUTPUT;i++)
  {
    if(i<n)
      des[i]=src[i];
    else
      des[i]='\0';
  }
}
```

Why won't it crush when printing a string or char by char? Where does the terminating NUL come from here?
It's for Reek's Pointers on C, and is supposed to copy n characters, filling with NUL when, des>=src.But when src>des it should copy all chars without terminating NUL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `copy_n` function `for` loop uses the constant `MAXOUTPUT` as the guard in the loop; and `MAXOUTPUT` has a value 10.

Comment: As it's supposed to, but when I print my 10 char output, where does '\0' come from? How can printf know when to stop printing, and so does my printing loop?

Comment: The `printf()` in the output loop is expected to invoke undefined behaviour, which however **not necessarily** needs to lead to a crash.

Comment: Exactly, but it doesn't. That's my question here.

Comment: but at the point when it checks if output[10]=='\0', it stops, what are the chances that there is that value, if I didn't put it there?

Comment: Ah, I see... It's possible that the for loop for printing is running past the memory allocated for `output`, but it just so happens to run into a 0 value.  On another compiler, or another machine, or at another time, this might core dump.